# Ruby application monitoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance

I currently have a Rails application that runs in AWS. I am looking for a way to graphically view my logs. request-log-analyzer is great and the database feature is nice however I need something that gives me basically that view but more long term. My logs are rotated daily.

Is there either a way for request-log-analzyer to update a live database or is there another host-able (our logs have PHI) solution that would work in this fashion?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like LogStash (https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash)